# UnicodeEncodeError with esy.osmfilter package

Tags: python, json, encoding, openstreetmap

I got an `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1-4: character maps to <undefined>` when I using *esy.osmfilter* package (version 1.0.7) to filter an OSM [.*pbf](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/liechtenstein.html) file and then save it to a *.json file with the following code:

```
import os

from esy.osmfilter import Node, Way, Relation
from esy.osmfilter import run_filter

PBF_inputfile = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'liechtenstein-latest.osm.pbf')
JSON_outputfile = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'liechtenstein-latest_river.json')

prefilter = {Node: {}, Way: {'waterway': ['river', ], }, Relation: {}}
whitefilter = []
blackfilter = []

[Data, _] = run_filter('noname',
                       PBF_inputfile,
                       JSON_outputfile,
                       prefilter,
                       whitefilter,
                       blackfilter,
                       NewPreFilterData=True,
                       CreateElements=False,
                       LoadElements=False,
                       verbose=True)

print(len(Data['Node']))
print(len(Data['Relation']))
print(len(Data['Way']))
```

I followed the [tutorial](https://gitlab.com/dlr-ve-esy/esy-osmfilter) and used tags like `{'waterway': ['stream', ], }`, `{'waterway': ['canal', ], }`, `{'waterway': ['dam', ], }`, etc. in the `prefilter` and they were all error-free. Then I found that the tag `{'waterway': ['river', ], }` will cause the error mentioned above. The same situation I received with the [Berlin](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/berlin.html) data. Then I tried with the [Delaware](http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/delaware.html) data, which was error-free. So I thought it might be related to the **German** words? My default encoding is `'utf-8'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error is fixed with version 1.0.11

Answer (score 2):

I believe this bug is a pure Windows bug. Please use esy-osmfilter on a linux machine for the moment. This error results from an external library, however I will fix this within the next days.